# JavascriptMCV to Angular migration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration, javascriptmvc

I have a huge client-side web application written in JavascriptMCV framework ~50 views, around 500.000 javascript code lines. Everything is built in JavascirptMVC formation using separate files for Controllers, Models and Views for each view = web page. The time has come to migrate to one of the modern javascript frameworks - I'm thinking about Angular and I'm starting to make an initial research about time estimations and human resources needed.
Are there some known techniques for doing that? If someone can point me to some article or knowledge base it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are tools or special techniques to do this, but you could create an angular app around your current app. 
You create an angular app from scratch, with a shared 'main' view (could be a new html page) which then uses ng-view (with angular-route) to load all your current HTML pages as partials. That way a lot of the page-linking can remain intact.. I do think that from that point, a lot of refactoring is required to make it an actual angular app.. Which raises the question, on what grounds do you think it's beneficial to migrate to a different framework when the old one is still working fine?